# How to execute an sql script file against an SQLite 3 database file?

Tags: sqlite

What is an SQLite 3 (3.7.11) analogue of MySQL's

```
mysql -p -u username database_name < file.sql
```

to execute all the queries in a given SQL script file against a specified database?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This should work:

```
[someone@somewhere ~]$ echo "select * from sometable;" > file.sql
[someone@somewhere ~]$ sqlite3 file.db < file.sql 
10/02/2012
11/01/2012
09/03/2012
```

Comment: Almost exactly the same as in MySQL. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The following should work as well:

```
 echo "SELECT id, username, email FROM fos_user_user;" | sqlite3 app/data.db3
```

Comment: This is not related to question