# How do I execute sqlite3 file into a database in mac terminal?

Tags: database, sqlite

I've tried the other suggestions on stackoverflow but can't seem to get it right. Nothing really works?

So say I have an sql file called afile.sql which contains sql commands for creating tables as well as inserting information into those tables, how do I run all these statements so that tables are created in a database I made in the terminal?

I have tried 
[someone@somewhere ~]$ echo "select * from sometable;" > file.sql
[someone@somewhere ~]$ sqlite3 file.db < file.sql

from this link [How to execute an sql script file against an SQLite 3 database file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045035/how-to-execute-an-sql-script-file-against-an-sqlite-3-database-file)

and a few others. 
Should I be running the "insert sql command file into database" outside of sqlite3 or in sqlite 3?

I have tried:
DATA.db < afile.sql(in sqlite3)
sqlite3 DATA.db < afile.sql (not in sqlite3)

and also
.read afile.sql
DATA.db

Nothing seems to work.

Screenshots:

[image: try 1]

[image: try 2]

[image: still no database with instances stored in it =(]

Still no database with instances stored in it =(

Comment: Some of your tries should have worked. Show screenshots.

Comment: @CL. I have added screenshots to the answer. Note that I am using terminal in the location where the sql file is located.

Comment: @C.L I know it's against the rules but I have to sincerely thank you so much for helping me. Ive been stuck on this for several days and absolutely didnt know what to do. Thank you thank you thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```
sqlite3 data.db < c291.sql
```

must be run from the OS shell, i.e., from the `$` prompt.

The commands

```
.open data.db
.read c291.sql
```

must be run from within the SQLite shell, i.e., from the `sqlite>` prompt.